# How can I set a custom domain in a Salesforce community?

Tags: community, login-errors, login, employee-community

### Background

We have a salesforce community called `mycompany.force.com/`
We also have a custom domain: `mycompany.my.salesforce.com` where users have Company Community Licenses. Because my users have that license which is a special one, they cannot log in from the standard community login page and that is why we created a custom domain (to create a custom login page and redirect users to the community). From our custom login page, we redirect users to our community.

The problem arose when we created a CNAME pointing to our custom domain; instead of taking us to the custom login page, it is redirecting us to the standard Salesforce login (so users cannot login to the community).

### We have tried several things to fix this issue:

1. Create a CNAME pointing to `MyCompany.force.com.` 
   This is redirecting to **na1.salesforce.com** (Instead of going to my community login page)
2. Create a CNAME pointing to `MyCompany.OrgID18.live.siteforce.com`
   My domain name has a TXT record that equals 00XXX000000ivokeac with no punctuation.
   My domain name is a subdomain of an another domain in my organization.
   This redirects me to **https://na1.salesforce.com/**.

Nothing seems to work though.
Any ideas on anything else we can try?
Thank you!

Comment: If your community domain is 'mycompany.force.com/' then why do you want to add a CNAME record for it? Also what is your custom domain URL? From your explanation, It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @SarojBera I have completed the question, I hope you can understand it now.

Comment: Aidan provided a excellent link on this. Please let me know if you find any challenge following the stes.  Also Internal Users can not access community from community login page, they need to access Salesforce first and access the Community from there. https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000212153&language=en_US

Comment: Hello Saroj, yes Internal Users cannot access community from login page, that is why I built a custom login page which works well. I updated the information, something else I've tried (the TXT with the org ID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@CamilaHeitz Let me try to explain with an example. As you mentioned yourdomain is a subdomain of another domain, so I am referring your domain as subdomain.

1. First create a CNAME record for `http://subdomain.maindomain.com` as
   `subdomain.maindomain.com.orgid18.live.siteforce.com`.
2. After the CNAME is created in DNS server, add the domain in your org
   **Setup > Domain Management > Domains > "Add a domain"**.
3. As per Salesforce you have to use a certificate, make sure you’ve
   already added it using Certificate and Key Management before you try
   to attach it to your domain. Details available in Aidan's link.
4. After adding the domain go to **Setup > Develop > Sites**. Open your
   community site in edit mode by clicking on Site Label. Add "**New
   Custom URL**" by selecting http://subdomain.maindomain.com from the
   list. I think you are missing this step.

Hope this will helps.

Comment: Thank you @Saroj Bera we implemented step 4 (without the 3rd step as we don't need a certificate) and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Have you read this guide? https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000212707&language=en_US

One important thing to note is that you have to set up the CNAME to MyCompany.OrgID18.live.siteforce.com first (even though it appears to go nowhere). Then you can generate a CSR, get that signed, and put it into SF.

SF will check your CNAME when you have uploaded the signed certificate and come to configure the custom domain.

Comment: Hello Aidan, we don't need a certificate for this, it is still going to eu5.salesforce.com (I've updated the info). Thank you.