# Custom domain registration

Tags: community, custom-domain

I have followed steps provided at following knowledge article to setup a Custom domain for communities

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000205653&type=1

After properly setting up the CNAME, salesforce was able to search for the CNAME and successfully saved the Domain. I have also created the custom URL to setup the community linking with the domain.

However, now when I enter the custom domain url i.e. www.abc.pqr.com, instead of maintaining the URL masking, it is redirecting to the community URL i.e. https://abc.force.com.

Am I missing anything??

Comment: I have provided the steps for Custom domain setup in this [SFSE link](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80385/how-can-i-set-a-custom-domain-in-a-salesforce-community/81057#81057). Please check if you have completed all steps.

Comment: It is properly redirecting to the community page, but the problem is with the URL. The URL shouldn't change from custom domain to force.com community url.

Comment: It shouldn't. Check your CNAME setup in this tool https://mxtoolbox.com/CNAMELookup.aspx. Then check if there is any re-direction rule is setup in the backend http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time on the issue, here are my findings: (Current scenario is to mask the Public facing community page URLs with customer branded URLs,  and I am assuming that CNAME config on customer website DNS is already completed.)

- While setting up the custom domain, if user has selected "This domain is HTTP-only and does not serve HTTPS" option for "How this domain serve HTTPS"

  1. HTTPS version of the custom domain will display "Your connection is not secure page"
  2. If user has selected, "Require secure connections" on the Force.com section of related community, HTTP version of the custom domain will be resolved properly, but will be redirected back to Salesforce community URL (losing the URL masking)
  3. If "Require secure connections" setting is disabled, it will work like a charm, but NO HTTPS.

---

- To serve HTTPS, users will need to upload the Customer's CA signed certificate to Salesforce