# Only custom Domain should be able to see on google for community URL

Tags: community, custom-domain

I've created a community, and customize the domain name for community.

consider
my community url : www.xyz.force.com
customized domain name for community : www.xyz.com

When I'm searching for website in google, it shows the pages with link like; www.xyz.force.com/...
This should not be happen. 
means customer not able to see the custom domain name for website.

Customr should be able to see the link on google like; www.xyz.com/...

Please suggest the workaround.

Comment: How long ago did you set up the domain www.xyz.com, as sometimes it can take up to 72 hours for the new DNS to propagate.

Comment: @SarojBera It set up more than 2-3 week ago.

Comment: Can you please check if you have followed all the steps I explained in this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80385/how-can-i-set-a-custom-domain-in-a-salesforce-community

Comment: @SarojBera yes I followed all mentioned steps. "www.xyz.com" is working fine

Comment: As I understand, the issue is resolved now. Is that correct?

Comment: @SarojBera No. my issue is not solved yet. I just answered to your above  question in which you provide link.

Comment: As it is a public domain, could you please share the URL?

Comment: @SarojBera my website link: www.shipperman.us.  please search on google "shipperman contact us"  and check the first link.